# BNB Sidechain Application, why a new block is created by a new miner address?

Tags: blockchain, sidechain-technology

I built a BAS network with only 3 validators (Ankr guider) and I noticed that for every new block generated, a corresponding new miner address is generated.

This is different from BNB mainnet, all blocks are generated only by defined validators.

Can you help me understand why there is this difference?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it's about the blockscuot configuration, just need to set BLOCK_TRANSFORMER=base

Answer (score -2):

few questions that would help me answer this properly:

- Can you provide more details about how you've configured your BSC sidechain? Specifically, how have you set up your validators and consensus algorithm?
- Are the validators being rotated for each new block? If so, how is this rotation being managed?
- Can you provide more details about the new addresses that are being generated for each block? Are these addresses associated with new validators, or are they associated with existing validators?
- What kind of transactions are being processed on your network? Are these transactions possibly leading to the creation of new addresses?
- Are you seeing any error messages or unusual log entries that might indicate what's going wrong?
- You mentioned that this behavior is different from what you see on the BSC mainnet. Can you provide more details about how you've compared your sidechain with the mainnet?

In terms of high level thoughts on what might be going wrong- The behavior you're observing might be due to the consensus algorithm used in your BSC sidechain network. BSC uses PoSA, which is a combination of PoA & DPoS.

In PoA networks, blocks are validated by a set of pre-approved validators. In DPoS networks, block validators are elected by token holders. The PoSA consensus algorithm combines these two approaches.

In your sidechain network, it's possible that the validators are being rotated for each new block. This is a common practice in PoA and DPoS networks to ensure decentralization and security. By rotating validators, the network can prevent any single validator from gaining too much power.

However, this should not result in a new address for each block. The validator's address should remain the same, even if they are not currently the active validator. If you're seeing a new address for each block, there might be something else going on.

Here are a few things you could check:

- Make sure your validator set is configured correctly. If there are more validators than you expect, this could explain the additional addresses.
- Make sure the consensus algorithm is configured correctly. If the algorithm is set to rotate validators too frequently, this could result in a new address for each block.
- There might be a bug or misconfiguration in your sidechain network that's causing this behavior. Check your network's configuration and code to see if there's anything that could be causing this issue.

Let me know if any of this is helpful and if you can answer some or all of my questions I can offer further help :)

-$

Comment: The sidechain configuration is the same what Ankr team provide in this github url: https://github.com/Ankr-network/bas-devnet-setup

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT (you've rapidly posted quite a bit of ChatGPT today)